# Is it normal to see lazy loaded module in webpack bundle analyzer?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

**Problem**

My problem is that webpack analyzer keeps showing me the module that I don't want. I don't know if it's normal or not.

**Code**

```
import React, { ReactElement, Suspense } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const SwaggerUI = React.lazy(() => import('swagger-ui-react'));

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

const App = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <SwaggerUI url='https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json' />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**How I run analyzer**

package.json:

```
"analyzer:prod": "BUNDLE_ANALYZER=true NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production"
```

command:

```
npm run analyzer:prod
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: You should care more about if "lazy load" is working or not. So, my question - Is the lazy load working as expected in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is normal that it is showing you lazy loaded components as well. Those components will be loaded lazily (at user's click or request), but we still care about their sizes and want to analyze those details in this view.